# Unable to run Java code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

So i am very new to Visual Studio Code, and can't figure out why my code is not printing. I used the maven projekt plugin to create a maven project. However since i created the project my code stopped printing to the terminal.

Im trying something as simple as:

```
public class hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi"); 
    }
}
```

However nothing gets printed to the console? Anybody got an ideer as to why that is? It worked fine before i created a maven projekt.

[image]

As you can see on the image, the code runs fine, but nothing is printed to the terminal, output section, debug console or the problems section. I would expect "Hi" to be printed somewhere?!

Comment: A small side note: The convetion for class names in Java is the first letter is capitalized. So write `public class Hi ` instead of `public class hi`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Does it solve your question? Kindly let me know if you have any other confusions.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot in your question, you're debugging `Main.java`:

[image]

Click [image] in the left side bar, it should be `Launch Main` selected to run and debug in your project, change it back to **Launch Current File**:

[image]

Then run or debug `Hi.java` again, it should give right result:

[image]